# Recoding non-mutually exclusive variable categories with grepl()

Tags: r, case, grepl, recode, mutual-exclusion

When I try to use this code to recode non - mutually exclusive variable categories, it does not work how I would like. For example, the post with the caption, "this post is about both a dog and space" could go in either 'animal_post' or 'other_post'. However, no matter what it always codes it as an 'animal_post' - as seen in code block 1. It only recodes as 'other_post' if I switch the order of the recode instructions itself - as seen in code block 2. Is there a way to recode non-mutually exclusive data without it defaulting to the first option?

```
#Code block 1

post_caption <- c("This post is about a dog", "This post is about a cat", "This post is about a walrus", "This post is about space", "this post is about both a dog and space")
post_name <- c("dog account", "dog_account", "walrus_account", "space_account", "space_account")

case_when(
  grepl(paste(c("dog", "cat", "walrus"), collapse = "|"), post_caption) ~ "animal_post",
  grepl(paste(c("space", "rocks", "trees"), collapse = ""), post_caption) &  grepl(paste(c("space", "rocks", "trees"), collapse = "|"), post_name)~ "other_post",
  TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )

[1] "animal_post" "animal_post" "animal_post" "other_post"  "animal_post"
```

```
#Code block 2

post_caption <- c("This post is about a dog", "This post is about a cat", "This post is about a walrus", "This post is about space", "this post is about both a dog and space")
post_name <- c("dog account", "dog_account", "walrus_account", "space_account", "space_account")

case_when(
  grepl(paste(c("space", "rocks", "trees"), collapse = "|"), post_caption) & grepl(paste(c("space", "rocks", "trees"), collapse = "|"), post_name)~ "other_post",
  grepl(paste(c("dog", "cat", "walrus"), collapse = "|"), post_caption) ~ "animal_post",
  TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )

#[1] "animal_post" "animal_post" "animal_post" "other_post" "other_post"
```

Comment: If you don't default to the first option, what decision rule do you want to apply? If the recoded vector should only contain one category per post, you must decide which category gets prioritized.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way I could set additional conditions that would overrule a certain order if specific conditions were met.

Comment: Ah well, in that case you need another vector (or several, but they will be combined into one vector, eventually) providing these additional conditions.